# Which senses do transformers possess?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series

From the movies we know that Transformers can

1. See

It also seems that they can

2. Smell

This is "proved" by Ironhide's phrase in the beginning of the "*Revenge of the Fallen*", when he refers to a Decepticon

> He is here, I **smell** him.

Also when Autobots first meet Sam, Ratchet mentions that Sam has high level of hormones, which, I suppose, he "sniffed".

It is also clear that they can

3. Hear

Do they have any other ways of getting information about the outer world? Do they, as super-advanced machines, have any detectors or radars? I am quite sure they do, because they drive somehow, while their eyes are somewhere deep under the hood.

---

I have only watched Michael "Logical Plot" Bay movies.

Comment: Side note: I smell him may just be an expression rather than literally smelling.

Comment: To add to @TheLethalCarrot 's comment, "I smell him" is not just an expression, it's actually a derogatory one.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot but when he says it, he literally sniffs

Answer (score 1):

They certainly have senses of direction, balance, duration, pain. These are all rather self-evident from the movies. One would assume a sense of touch, as many of their interactions would be questionably possible without it.

Comment: I don't think "sense of direction" is a literal sense.

Comment: @Buzz why do you think that?  Many animals regularly migrate based on magnetoreception.  It seems like it would be trivial for a transformer to have a compass, or pick up GPS signals, maybe triangulate based on radio waves, or something else like that.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoreception